# VPNにおけるサーバ→クライアント通信

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, vpc

掲題の通信について明確な情報が見つからなかった為、ご存じの方おられましたらご教示頂けますでしょうか。

#### 具体的な環境

- VPN: AWSのVPN（OpenVPN）
- 接続元: EC2インスタンス（Linux）
- 接続先: VPNクライアント(自宅のルータ配下のPC)
- 通信プロトコル: HTTP

**EC2インスタンスから**自宅のWEBサーバにHTTPリクエストを送信したいです。

当然のことながら、VPNクライアントからEC2インスタンスへの通信はVPN経由で問題ありません。
逆の通信については、一般的に困難なのでしょうか。

### 追記 2022/08/16

[こちらのコメントに対して](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/90459/15316%20%E8%BF%94%E4%BF%A1%E9%81%85%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82%E3%81%94%E4%B8%81%E5%AF%A7%E3%81%AB%E3%81%94%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E9%A0%82%E3%81%8D%E3%80%81%E8%AA%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20%20%20%20%20%20%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E%E3%82%92%E7%B0%A1%E7%B4%A0%E5%8C%96%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E3%80%81%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E5%BF%B5%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E8%A3%9C%E8%B6%B3%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20%20%3E%20%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%85%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E9%85%8D%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AEPC%20%20%E4%BE%BF%E5%AE%9C%E4%B8%8A%E3%80%81PC%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%98%E8%BC%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8C%E5%8E%B3%E5%AF%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%20Raspberry%20Pi%20%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20%E3%83%A9%E3%82%BA%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%81%ABWEB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8C%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A%E3%80%81%E3%81%93%E3%81%AEWEB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%ABEC2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E7%9B%AE%E7%9A%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20VPN%E7%B5%8C%E7%94%B1%E3%81%A7EC2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%ABHTTP%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E9%80%81%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%80%81%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E9%80%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20%20%3E%20%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81PC%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%AF%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%80%81PC%E3%81%AE%E5%91%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8BWEB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E7%AD%89%E3%81%AF%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82%20%20PC%E8%87%AA%E4%BD%93%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AF%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%80%82%20%20%3E%20%E4%BA%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AENIC%E3%82%92%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20%20%E5%85%B7%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%ABNIC%E3%81%AF%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%20-%20VPN%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%AE%E6%83%B3NIC%EF%BC%9A%60tun0%60%20-%20%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86NIC%EF%BC%9A%60eth0%60%20%20%60tun0%60%20%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AFEC2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E9%80%9A%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%80%82%20%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82)
返信遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。ご丁寧にご回答頂き、誠にありがとうございます。

説明を簡素化しようと思い、言葉足らずあったかと思いますので念のため補足いたします。

> 自宅のルータ配下のPC

便宜上、PCと記載しましたが厳密には Raspberry Pi になります。
ラズパイにはWEBサーバプロセスが起動しており、このWEBサーバにEC2インスタンスからアクセスすることが目的です。
VPN経由でEC2インスタンスにHTTPリクエストを送りたいし、その逆もしたいです。
ラズパイはVPNクライアントであり、WEBサーバとなります。

> ですので、PCへの通信は可能ですが、PCの周りにあるWEBサーバー等は見えません。

PC（ラズパイ）自体へは通信可能ということでしょうか。

> 二つのNICをブリッジ接続に設定すれば通信可能になります。

具体的にNICは以下のようになっています。

- VPNの仮想NIC：`tun0`
- 物理NIC：`eth0`

`tun0` まではEC2インスタンスから通信できているということでしょうか。
そういうことであれば何かイメージできたかもしれません。

Comment: VPN 関係なしに自宅サーバによそから接続するために必要な事項って理解できていますか？　固定 IP アドレスサービスとか DNS とか  DDNS とか家庭用ルータの NAPT 設定とかそれに伴うセキュリティ管理とか。それができるのなら（ネット契約上・管理者の技術スキル上）問題ないはずです。自信がないならやめておくほうが吉。

Comment: 参考に、AWS Client VPNに限って言えば、クライアントはあなたのPCのようにVPCからさらにNAPTされている環境にいます。

Comment: RasPi 上の web サーバを EC2 インスタンスで新たに建ててしまうのが一番手っ取り早くわかりやすい気がします。なぜあえて自宅内のネットワーク (しかも VPN クライアント) に外部から接続する必要があるのかを精査、質問に含めた方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tun0 まではEC2インスタンスから通信できているということでしょうか。

EC2インスタンスから Raspberry Pi の tun0 に割り当てられた IPアドレスに向けた通信であれば、ルーティングを設定すれば可能かもしれません。
ただし、ルーティング先の「クライアント VPN ネットワークインターフェイス」の IPアドレスは可変ですし、そもそも、AWS Client VPN サービス側で許可されていない可能性があります。

別の方法として、Raspberry Pi から EC2インスタンスに、SSH RemoteForward (-R オプション) で逆向きのトンネルを作成する方法が考えられます。

Answer (score 2):

下記の回答は、コメント及び質問が編集される前の質問に対して回答であったため、**VPNクライアントを動作させているPCとは別に自宅内にWebサーバが存在する**と言う前提になっています。そのため、編集後の質問に対しての回答としては、あっていないないようになります。ただ、PCとWebサーバが別であった場合は参考になるかと思いますので、回答はこのまま、残しておきます。

---

PC等で動作する一般的なVPNクライアント(OpenVPNならvpnux Client等)を用いた場合、そのような通信は非常に困難です。PCのルーター化や適切なルーティングテーブル設定、または、ブリッジでの接続をすれば不可能ではありませんが、それなりのネットワークに関する知識が必要になります。

一般に、VPNクライアントの接続は、VPNクライアントが動いているPCを仮想的にVPNサーバー側のネットワークに繋げるというものです。PCだけが、ぽんっと向こうのネットワークに繋がったような感じで、PCの周りにある端末は置いてけぼりになります。逆に向こうのネットワークからみると、新たなPC一個だけがネットワーク上に現れたという感じです。ですので、PCへの通信は可能ですが、PCの周りにあるWEBサーバー等は見えません。

ネットワークとしては、PCには物理NICの他に仮想的なNICがあって、それぞれ別のネットワークに繋がっているというイメージです(実際に、OS上も二つのNICとして認識されています)。二つのNICを持つPCを別々のネットワークに繋いでも、それらのネットワーク同士が勝手に通信可能にならないと言うことはわかりますよね？ただ、この状況でも、PCでIPルーティングを有効にして、それぞれのネットワークで適切なルーティングテーブルを設定する、または、二つのNICをブリッジ接続に設定すれば通信可能になります。初めに言った話はこれになります。PCに二つのNICがある場合でどのように設定すれば良いのかわからなければ、VPNクライアントを用いて同じようなことをすることは難しいでしょう。

なお、拠点間VPNと言われるネットワーク同士をVPN繋いで双方向に通信可能になる仕組みがありますが、実際の所は、PCよりは設定しやすいVPN対応ネットワーク機器やLinuxサーバーでルーティングまたはブリッジ接続を適切に行っているだけになります。

Comment: 返信遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。ご丁寧にご回答頂き、誠にありがとうございます。  
  
説明を簡素化しようと思い、言葉足らずあったかと思いますので念のため補足いたします。

> 自宅のルータ配下のPC

便宜上、PCと記載しましたが厳密には Raspberry Pi になります。
ラズパイにWEBサーバプロセスが起動しており、このWEBサーバにEC2インスタンスからアクセスすることが目的です。
VPN経由でEC2インスタンスにHTTPリクエストを送りたいし、その逆もしたいです。

> ですので、PCへの通信は可能ですが、PCの周りにあるWEBサーバー等は見えません。

PC自体へは通信可能ということでしょうか。

> 二つのNICをブリッジ接続に設定すれば通信可能になります。

具体的にNICは以下のようになっています。
- VPNの仮想NIC：`tun0`
- 物理NIC：`eth0`

`tun0` まではEC2インスタンスから通信できているということでしょうか。
そういうことであれば何かイメージできたかもしれません。

Comment: この回答は前提が全く違っているため、今回の質問には全く役に立つ事はありません。 **忘れて下さい。** また、質問は簡潔さより正確さを重視して下さい。私たちは「質問文に書かれていること」しかわかりません。情報が欠落しているよりは過剰であるほうがマシになります。なるべく、多くの情報を記載した方が本当に知りたかった内容の回答がつきやすくなります。